# ReactiveUi: How can I replace the default IViewLocator when using AutoFac?

Tags: c#, wpf, autofac, reactiveui, splat

High!

I am trying to replace the default IViewLocator of ReactiveUi/Splat in WPF. I am using AutoFac as container.

My goal is very simple: ReactiveUi/Splat should use my custom implementation of IViewLocator when resolving a view for view model.

I really read every availabe tutorial and stackoverflow thread, but nothing helped.

Currently I do the following while bootstrapping: (I tried many different things...)

```
namespace MDM
{
    public static class Bootstrapper
    {
        private static AutofacDependencyResolver? Locator;
        private static IContainer? Container;

        public static void Register()
        {
            Splat.Locator.CurrentMutable.InitializeSplat();
            Splat.Locator.CurrentMutable.InitializeReactiveUI();
            Splat.Locator.CurrentMutable.RegisterConstant<IViewLocator>(new ViewLocator());

            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterType<MainWindowView>().As<IViewFor<MainWindowViewModel>>().SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterType<EinstellungenView>().As<IViewFor<EinstellungenViewModel>>().SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterType<MainWindowViewModel>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterType<EinstellungenViewModel>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();

            Locator = builder.UseAutofacDependencyResolver();
            builder.RegisterInstance(Locator);

            Locator.InitializeReactiveUI();
            Splat.Locator.SetLocator(Locator);

            Container = builder.Build();

            Locator.SetLifetimeScope(Container);

        }

        public static T Resolve<T>() where T : class
        {
            return Container!.Resolve<T>();
        }

    }
}
```

While debugging the following line of code in my IViewLocator is never hit:

```
public IViewFor? ResolveView<T>(T viewModel, string? contract = null)
{

}
```

**So my question is:** What do I need to do while bootstrapping, to tell ReactiveUi to use my IViewLocator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you decide to drop Splat (the IoC container used by ReactiveUI) and use Autofac, then you must go with it, especially when *registering* services.
Once you have registered a custom IoC container (properly), you shouldn't use Splat anymore to resolve any dependencies. Although Splat will redirect service requests to the Autofac container, I recommend against mixing the APIs.

```cs
var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

// TODO::Register application's dependencies with Autofac

/* Configure Splat to use Autofac */
var autofacResolver = containerBuilder.UseAutofacDependencyResolver();
containerBuilder.RegisterInstance(autofacResolver);
autofacResolver.InitializeReactiveUI();

// AFTER configuring the IoC redirect, register the Splat service overrides
containerBuilder.RegisterType<ViewLocator>()
  .As<IViewLocator>()
  .SingleInstance();

var container = containerBuilder.Build(); 
autofacResolver.SetLifetimeScope(container);
```

Don't use the *Service Locator* anti-pattern. The IoC container should not be distributed across the application. Neither as injected reference nor as static reference.
Use the *Abstract Factory* pattern instead.

For this reason, `IViewLocator.ResolveView` must use factories instead of the static `Resolve` method that you have implemented in your `Bootstrapper`.

Comment: Correct answer. Fantastic! It just works now. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm happy I could help. Good luck with your project.